# Converting "4:00AM" to ISO8601

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, elixir, ecto

The frontend is sending time values like "4:00AM" or "7:15PM" and I need to convert these to ISO8601 (i.e. "04:00:00" and "19:15:00" respectively) so that I can store them in a "time without time zone" column in PostgreSQL.

What is the easiest way to do this? I have Timex available, and am using Ecto.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres is flexible about date and time formats. You can just `cast` these strings:

```
select '4:00AM'::time, '7:15PM'::time
```

```
time     | time    
:------- | :-------
04:00:00 | 19:15:00
```

Comment: Basically you need to cast the parameters in the query. Assuming that you have a parameter `$1`, then `$1::time`.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 'timestamp(tz), date, time(tz), etc` are not stored in a format. Formatting is something you do on retrieval. So:

```
create table time_test(time_fld time);
insert into time_test values ('4:00AM');
insert into time_test values ('7:15PM');

 select time_fld from time_test ;
 time_fld 
----------
 04:00:00
 19:15:00
```

Just pass the string in and let Postgres do the work.

Comment: If I had been able to pass the string as is, I would not have asked the question. :)

When I pass `due_time: "4:00AM"`, Ecto returns `Due time is invalid`.

Comment: Well that would have useful information to provide in the original question. Looks like you will need to look at this [parsing](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/parsing.html)

Answer (score 0):

One might manually convert the value to the appropriate `Time` struct.

```rb
iex|1 ▶ [h, m, pm?] =
...|1 ▶   "4:00PM"
...|1 ▶   |> String.downcase()
...|1 ▶   |> String.split(~r/:|(?<=\d)(?=\D)/)
#⇒ ["4", "00", "pm"]
iex|2 ▶ m = String.to_integer(m)
iex|3 ▶ h =
...|3 ▶   if(match?("pm", pm?), do: 12, else: 0) + String.to_integer(h)
#⇒ 16
iex|4 ▶ Time.from_erl!({h, m, 0})
#⇒ ~T[16:00:00]
```